# It gives an error when checking the data when turning on the route

Tags: node.js

I need to check the entered data and user photo.

Here I keep the fields for verification

```
const validator = [
    check('name').exists().isLength({ min: 4, max: 20 }),
    check('email').exists().isEmail().normalizeEmail(),
    ...
];
```

Here I wipe everything

```
import { check, validationErrors } from 'express-validator/check';
import upload from'../config/multer.config.js';

router.post('/add', validator, (req, res) => {
    try {
        const errors = validationResult(req);
        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
            console.log(errors.array());
        }
        upload(req, res, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(422).json({
                    err: err
                });
            }
            if (!req.files.avatar) {
                return res.status(422).json({
                    err: 'Missing required image file'
                });
            }
        })
    .....
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
});
```

I get an error message on check `!error.isEmpty()`, here is my error code:

```
{ [ { location: 'body',
    param: 'name',
    value: undefined,
    msg: 'Invalid value' },
  { location: 'body',
    param: 'name',
    value: undefined,
    msg: 'Invalid value' },
  { location: 'body',
    param: 'email',
    value: undefined,
    msg: 'Invalid value' },
  { location: 'body',
    param: 'email',
    value: undefined,
    msg: 'Invalid value' },
    .....
 } ]
  ....
  Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

My problem is that I have not verified the data entered by the user and the error will work

Help to deal with my problem, I need to check the entered user data and photos, but I can’t handle errors when the user enters more than the required number of images

My multer.config.js:

```
import multer, { memoryStorage } from 'multer';
import path from 'path';

let storage = memoryStorage()
let upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    limits: {
        fileSize: 1000000 
    },
    fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
        let ext = path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase();
        if (ext !== '.png' && ext !== '.jpg' && ext !== '.jpeg') {
            return cb(null, false);
        }
        cb(null, true);
    }
}).fields([{
        name: 'avatar',
        maxCount: 1
    },
    {
        name: 'photos',
        maxCount: 3
    }
]);

export default upload;
```

Comment: change  `validationErrors` to `validationResult`

Comment: @dev07 I tried, there is no difference

Comment: what is the issue exactly ? the error code which you have posted is just an object from validationErrors method,its not an error

Comment: can you show the content of the file `multer.config.js` because I'm trying to replicate it ..thank you

Comment: My problem is that I can not check the entered fields by the user validator and check the avatar user multer

Comment: here `if (!error.isEmpty()) {
            console.log(error);
        }` do `console.log(errors.array())` and let me know what is the output

Comment: @dev07 Thank you for being interested in my problem, I have errors that fields are displayed, I entered all the data in the fields and they are not empty. Why it happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out, read the documents and found that:
`Multer adds a body object and a file or files object to the request object. The body object contains the values of the text fields of the form, the file or files object contains the files uploaded via the form.`

I had to change `const errors = validationResult(req);`, on `const errors = validationResult(req.body);`

My work code:

```
router.post('/signup', validatorSignup, (req, res) => {
    try {
        upload(req, res, (err) => {
            const errors = validationResult(req.body);
            if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
                return res.status(422).json({
                    err: errors.array()
                });
            }
            if (err) {
                return res.status(422).json({
                    err: err
                });
            }
            if (!req.files.user_avatar) {
                return res.status(422).json({
                    name: "MulterError",
                    message: 'Missing required image file',
                    field: "user_avatar"
                });
            } 
    ....   
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
});
```